# is there a way to render things in front / over other? im trying to remake this character material

Tags: materials, shaders, transparency, shader-nodes

[image: the character im trying to remake in blender]

Im trying to make the material of this character in blender, i discovered that he's not transparent but has a complex material in the head that make the blob with the eyes appear in front of the material of the head making this fake transparent look. this is a character from fortnite called rippley. In unreal engine he doesn't have a alpha material but an opaque one. is there anyone who can help me with this?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0SDF5b0Cxc heres a video of how is in the game

Comment: this is how the model looks in blender [link](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1188140442391433217/1215701991276417095/image.png?ex=65fdb5b5&is=65eb40b5&hm=05a1b8d6e00223255b7d772c23617bb614a8f8afbff59b500955a7a003f228c9&=&format=webp&quality=lossless&width=439&height=350)

Comment: it turns around 360° in your video and it looks like he has a transparent helmet, then the green ball as head

Comment: he isn't in reality that's the fact, it has an effect that makes the green ball head over the helmet

Comment: https://fortnite.gg/cosmetics?id=378 here's another video for demonstration

Comment: Have you checked whether the "head ball" and the eyes are inside the character model? Are they individual objects or mesh parts? -- Do you want to animate it? EEVEE or Cycles?

Comment: Are you after the *effect* or an imitation of the shader Unreal uses? If the latter, it might be worthwhile to point out how you know the material is opaque, and provide some additional information about it. By the way, glass shaders in Blender are also opaque.

Comment: Recreating this effect in Blender is no simple task without having a better understanding of how the shader is working within the game engine and what render passes or texture maps are involved in the translucent jelly look and the location of the eyes seems to be based on it's orientation to the camera.

Comment: the "head ball" is inside the mesh, in unreal engine it works that the "head ball" gets rendered in front of the outside mesh like the "in front" option in the viewport shading option

Comment: blunder i would like to use eevee with this since it's a cartoony character and i have more experience with it

Comment: if someone can contact me on discord so i can share better model, screenshot my id is durrrmoth